# Data is suddenly deleted from Boost shared_array/ptr

Tags: c++, boost, std

I’m having some trouble with Boost shared pointers. The data pointed to by the pointers is suddenly deleted at an indeterminate time. In the current program (I’ve tried many other variantions) the data of `boost::shared_array<TableFieldsMap> retArray` is suddenly deleted in the switch construction after the case `MYSQL_TYPE_DOUBLE` case, after the loop has run through exactly 172 rows (there are 1000 rows in the table). But only when the method is called twice. The first run through works perfectly.

Specifically I pinpointed the problem to map-key being used in the assignment to the retArray. It works when I used a hard-coded string. But not a value of a local shared_array (fieldNameArray) (I first had scoped_array, but this I understand should not work), and not a local variable (tmpIndex).

```
retArray[rowIndex]["value"] = boost::lexical_cast<long double>(row[i]); // This works.
// This doesn't work: retArray[rowIndex][fieldNameArray[i]] = boost::lexical_cast<long double>(row[i]);
// This doesn't work either: retArray[rowIndex][tmpIndex.c_str()] = boost::lexical_cast<long double (row[i]);
```

Here is the header class:

```
#ifndef DATABASE_H
#define DATABASE_H

#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

#include <glog/logging.h>
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>
#include <boost/smart_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/variant.hpp>

#include <mysql.h>

#include <cppconn/driver.h>
#include <cppconn/exception.h>
#include <cppconn/resultset.h>
#include <cppconn/statement.h>
#include <cppconn/prepared_statement.h>

#include "../globals/globals.hpp"
#include "../exception/cassandra_exception.hpp"

struct mapCompare
{
    bool operator()(char const * a, char const * b)
    {
        return (strcmp(a, b) < 0);
    }
};

typedef map<const char*, boost::variant<short, int, long double, char*>, mapCompare > TableFieldsMap;

struct DataSet
{
    unsigned int rowCount;
    boost::shared_array<TableFieldsMap>data;
};

class Database
{
private:
    MYSQL *connection;

public:
    Database();
    ~Database();

    bool connect(const char *, const char *, const char *, const char *);
    DataSet select(const char*);
};

#endif
```

- and code:

  ```
  #include "database.hpp"
  Database::Database()
  {
      DLOG(INFO) << "::Database";
  }

  Database::~Database()
  {
      DLOG(INFO) << "~Database";

      if (connection) mysql_close(connection);
  }

  bool Database::connect(const char* server, const char* user, const char* password, const char* database)
  {
      DLOG(INFO) << ">> connect";

      connection = mysql_init(NULL);

      if (!connection)
      {
          cout << "Error" << endl;
          return (false);
      }

      if (!mysql_real_connect(connection, server, user, password, database, 0, NULL, 0))
      {
          cout << "Database init error (" << mysql_error(connection) << ")" << endl;
      }

      if (!connection)
      {
          cout << "Connection Failed!" << endl;
          return (false);
      }

      return (true);
  }

  DataSet Database::select(const char* query)
  {
      DLOG(INFO) << ">> select";

      MYSQL_RES *resultSet;
      MYSQL_ROW row;
      unsigned int fieldCount;
      MYSQL_FIELD* field;

      // Query database.
      if (mysql_query(connection, query)) throw MyException(string("Database select error (") + mysql_error(connection) + ")");

      // Handle result-set.
      resultSet = mysql_store_result(connection);
      if (resultSet == NULL) throw MyException(string("Database select error. Result-set is empty (") + mysql_error(connection) + ")");

      // Initialize return array.
      unsigned int rowCount = mysql_num_rows(resultSet);
      boost::shared_array<TableFieldsMap> retArray(new TableFieldsMap[rowCount]);

      // Obtain field names and types.
      fieldCount = mysql_num_fields(resultSet);
      boost::shared_array<const char *> fieldNameArray(new const char* [fieldCount]);
      boost::scoped_array<enum_field_types> fieldTypeArray(new enum_field_types[fieldCount]);
      unsigned int fieldIndex = 0;
      while ((field = mysql_fetch_field(resultSet)))
      {
          fieldNameArray[fieldIndex] = field -> name;
          fieldTypeArray[fieldIndex++] = field -> type;
      }

      // Fix?
      string tmpIndex;

      // Load data from result-set.
      unsigned int rowIndex = 0;
      while ((row = mysql_fetch_row(resultSet)) != NULL)
      {
          // Fields of the row.
          for (unsigned int i = 0; i < fieldCount; i++)
          {
              if (row[i] == NULL) throw MyException("Database error. Null.");

              switch (fieldTypeArray[i])
              {
                  // Medium int & Integer.
                  case MYSQL_TYPE_INT24 :
                  case MYSQL_TYPE_LONG :
                  retArray[rowIndex][fieldNameArray[i]] = boost::lexical_cast<int>(row[i]);
                  break;

                  case MYSQL_TYPE_DOUBLE :
                  try
                  {
                  retArray[rowIndex]["value"] = boost::lexical_cast<long double>(row[i]); // This works.
                  }
          catch (boost::bad_lexical_cast exception)
                  {
                      DLOG(ERROR) << "Error reading the phi table from database. Cast error. (" << rowIndex << ", " << row[i] << ")" << endl;
                      throw MyException("Error reading the phi table from database. Cast error.");
          }

                  // tmpIndex = string(fieldNameArray[i]);
                  // This doesn't work: retArray[rowIndex][fieldNameArray[i]] = boost::lexical_cast<long double>(row[i]);
                  // This doesn't work either: retArray[rowIndex][tmpIndex.c_str()] = boost::lexical_cast<long double>(row[i]);
                  break;

              case MYSQL_TYPE_VARCHAR :               // 15
              case MYSQL_TYPE_VAR_STRING :            // 253
              case MYSQL_TYPE_STRING :                // 254
              retArray[rowIndex][fieldNameArray[i]] = row[i];
              break;

                  case MYSQL_TYPE_DECIMAL :               // 0
                  case MYSQL_TYPE_TINY :                  // 1
                  case MYSQL_TYPE_SHORT :                 // 2
                  case MYSQL_TYPE_FLOAT :                 // 4
                  case MYSQL_TYPE_NULL :                  // 6
                  case MYSQL_TYPE_TIMESTAMP :             // 7
                  case MYSQL_TYPE_LONGLONG :              // 8
                  case MYSQL_TYPE_DATE :                  // 10
                  case MYSQL_TYPE_TIME :                  // 11
                  case MYSQL_TYPE_DATETIME :              // 12
                  case MYSQL_TYPE_YEAR :                  // 13
                  case MYSQL_TYPE_NEWDATE :               // 14
                  case MYSQL_TYPE_BIT :                   // 16
                  case MYSQL_TYPE_NEWDECIMAL :            // 246
                  case MYSQL_TYPE_ENUM :                  // 247
                  case MYSQL_TYPE_SET :                   // 248
                  case MYSQL_TYPE_TINY_BLOB :             // 249
                  case MYSQL_TYPE_MEDIUM_BLOB :           // 250
                  case MYSQL_TYPE_LONG_BLOB :             // 251
                  case MYSQL_TYPE_BLOB :                  // 252
                  default:
                  DLOG(FATAL) << "Database error. Unsupported datatype";
                  throw MyException("Database error. Unsupported datatype");
                  break;
              }
          rowIndex++;
          }
      }

      mysql_free_result(resultSet);

      DataSet retStruct;
      retStruct.rowCount = rowCount;
      retStruct.data = retArray;

      return (retStruct);
  }
  ```

...

Here is the calling method:

```
    include "My_database.hpp"

    MyDatabase::MyDatabase(string server, string user, string password, string database)
    {
        DLOG(INFO) << "::MyDatabase (1)";

        init(server.c_str(), user.c_str(), password.c_str(), database.c_str());
    }

    MyDatabase::MyDatabase(const char* server, const char* user, const char* password, const char* database)
    {
        DLOG(INFO) << "::MyDatabase (2)";

        init(server, user, password, database);
    }

    MyDatabase::~MyDatabase()
    {
        DLOG(INFO) << "~MyDatabase";
    }

    void MyDatabase::init(const char* server, const char* user, const char* password, const char* database)
    {
        DLOG(INFO) << ">> init";

        connect(server, user, password, database);
    }

    boost::shared_array<long double>MyDatabase::loadPhiTable()
    {
        DLOG(INFO) << ">> LoadPhiTable";

        // Select from database.
        DataSet selectData = select("SELECT value FROM phi");
        boost::shared_array<TableFieldsMap>phiArray = selectData.data;
        unsigned int rowCount = selectData.rowCount;

        // Initialize return array.
        boost::shared_array<long double> retArray(new long double[rowCount]);

        unsigned int i = 0;
        try
        {
            for (i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) retArray[i] = boost::get<long double>(phiArray[i]["value"]);
        }
        catch (boost::bad_get exception)
        {
            throw MyException(string("Error reading the phi table. Conversion error. (index: ") + boost::lexical_cast<string>(i) + ", value: " + boost::lexical_cast<string>(phiArray[i]["value"]) + ")");
        }

        return (retArray);
    }
```

Any other suggestions would also be appreciated. My first c++ program.

Comment: You should include the code making the calls to this function with the problem. lexical_cast can throw so are you catching?

Comment: Edited to include calling function.

Comment: Where are you catching the bad_lexical_cast exception?

Comment: I don't. I want it to crash if there is a cast exception. There's also the thing that it runs through ok one time, but crashes if run another time.

Comment: Why not catch the exception, log an error and then re-throw? Otherwise how will you know what went wrong? You'll have to analyse crash dumps. Are you always running it on the same data set?

Comment: That's right I ought to do that. I have added some exception catching (to the double case, which is the only one being used). The calls always use the same data. The exact same call being executed two times in a row fails on the second time through.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that

```
boost::shared_array<const char *> fieldNameArray = ...;
```

doesn't own the elements of the array, so they're left as dangling pointers when the indirected data disappears.  This is presumably happening within the MySQL API if the pointer returned by `mysql_fetch_field` indirects to pooled data.

The simplest fix would be to change `fieldNameArray` to contain `std::string`.